# How can I change column names without referencing old column names and without creating a new data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I know I can change column names by doing:

```
df = df.rename(columns = {old_name: new_name})
```

But I have to rename a lot and the old names are long so I wanna just pass in a list for the new names. If I make the new columns its own data frame this works fine:

```
ranks = sw[sw.columns[9:15]]
ranks.columns = ['ranking_1', 'ranking_2', 'ranking_3', 'ranking_4', 'ranking_5', 'ranking_6']
```

However if I try to just do it with the slice of columns without changing it to its own df, nothing happens:

```
sw[sw.columns[9:15]].columns = ['ranking_1', 'ranking_2', 'ranking_3', 'ranking_4', 'ranking_5', 'ranking_6']
```

How can I rename the columns and keep them in the original data frame?

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
sw[sw.columns[9:15]] = ['ranking_1', 'ranking_2', 'ranking_3', 'ranking_4', 'ranking_5', 'ranking_6']
```

changes the data of your `sw`, not the column names. A manual way to change the column names can be:

```
# new column names
new_cols = ['ranking_1', 'ranking_2', 'ranking_3', 'ranking_4', 'ranking_5', 'ranking_6']

# slice the columns name, replace the part you want and concatenate
sw.columns = list(sw.columns[:9]) + new_cols + list(sw.columns[15:])
```

Or you can also build the dictionary and use `rename`:

```
rename_dict = {a:b for a,b in zip(new_cols, sw.columns[9:15])}
sw.rename(columns=rename_dict)
```

Comment: I added .columns to the end to the end of sw[sw.columns[9:15]] (I edited above). Now I am referring to the columns not the ```sw``` data. So why doesn't that work?

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't work because when you do an assignment of `sw[sw.columns[9:15]].columns`, the first part is no longer a view but rather a copy. Much like [assignment with chaining index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E',
                           'F','G','H','I','J',
                           'K','L','M','N','O'])
col = list(df.columns)                # get them all
rankcol = ['ranking_1', 'ranking_2', 'ranking_3', 
           'ranking_4', 'ranking_5', 'ranking_6']

df.columns = col[:9]+rankcol
```